# CodeIgniter use model from model's constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I have two models, first one is dependent on the second one, and I need to call methods from the second one in the first one's constructor.

So far I have this:

**user**

```
class User extends CI_Model {

    protected $_attributes = array();

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('musers');
        foreach($this->musers->GetProfile() as $key => $val) {
            $this->_attributes[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    function __set($key, $val) {
        return $this->_attributes[$key] = $val;
    }

    function __get($key) {
        return $this->_attributes[$key];
    }
}
```

I have put this model in the `autoload` config file and here's what I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: load
Filename: models/user.php
Line Number: 20

Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in  path\to\models\user.php on line 9
```

There's also something strange - the first error (notice) refers to line `return $this->_attributes[$key];` while it surely should reference line `$this->load->model('musers');`.

I have tried loading model `musers` in autoload before the `user` model, but nothing helps. I have tried searching for this, but could not formulate the query well, I'm sure there are solutions to my problem.

As I understand this is because the constructor of the second model is called before CodeIgniter manages to load the loader class itself, but that's pretty odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model("musers", "musers");
    foreach($CI->musers->GetProfile() as $key => $val) {
        ......
}

    ......
```

Comment: You, Sir, are my today's hero, kudos to you! Didn't think of it, despite the fact I'm constantly writing libraries nowadays.

Comment: @Vlakarados glad you got it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$CI = &get_instance();//you need to define the instance for loading the second model musers
$CI->load->model('musers');
```